# What is the difference between “return my_view” and “return redirect(my_view)” and how to get a mixed result?

Tags: django, forms, redirect, view, request

I have a home in which I have a form that I get some info from students to suggest them some programs to apply to. The home view is as below:

```
def home(request):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    home_context = {}
    if request.POST:
        my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            #  do some stuff
            return programs(request)
    else:
        my_form = MyModelForm()
    home_context.update({'my_form': my_form, })
    return render(request, template_name, home_context)
```

In the second view, I have the same form and I want this form to be pre-occupied with the information I entered in the home page. That is why in the above, I passed my POST request to programs view that is as below:

```
def programs(request):
    template_name = 'programs.html'
    programs_context = {}
    if request.POST:
        my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            #  do some other stuff
    else:
        my_form = MyModelForm()
    programs_context.update({'my_form': my_form, })
    return render(request, template_name, programs_context)
```

The drawback of this strategy (passing the POST request in the home view to the programs_view) is that the url in url bar does not change to 'example.com/programs' and stays as 'example.com' . I will have some problems including problems in pagination of the programs. 
The alternative is that I do this:

```
def home(request):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    home_context = {}
    if request.POST:
        my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            #  do some stuff
            return redirct(programs)
    else:
        my_form = MyModelForm()
    home_context.update({'my_form': my_form, })
    return render(request, template_name, home_context)
```

The problem with this altenative strategy is that I do not see my_form in programs view pre-occupied with the data submitted in the home page.
I want to get a mixed result. Have the form pre-occupied and see the url changed to 'example.com/programs'.
Note: I have not shown what is written in the url patterns and in the template and I expect these are implied.
What I expect is a solution without adding info to sessions. I just want to pass POST request to programs view.
If there is no way without adding data to the session, the best method of adding data to session is appreciated.

Please note that when push the form submit button in the home page, I want to be referred to request.POST of the programs view. This is a positive point of alternative 1 that I am currently using.

In the first method, If I enter 'example.com/programs', the get part of the programs view is triggered and if I submit the form on the home page, the get part of the home view and then the POST part of the programs view is triggered. This is the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you search more for that issue, you'll find that either redirect of POST request or passing variables/context via redirect is not possible.

Either your proposed solution with storing POST data in the `request.session` is not optimal.

You can `return redirect(reverse('urlname') + query_string)` with adding GET querystring to the url and prefill the form from that querystring in the programs view. It would be much cleaner solution to this.

Comment: The redirect function takes the url as the first argument, reverse reverses the url pathname to the url and by + you will add the dumped POST data as querystring. Example `return redirect(reverse('urlname') + '?' + urllib.parse.parse_qs(request.POST))`

And later in the other view. You can instantiate the form with the prefilled data from `request.GET`.

Comment: I returned ```redirect(reverse('urlname') + '?' + urllib.parse.parse_qs(request.POST))``` but I got this error: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'decode'